# Spread table column long to wide

Tags: awk

I have the following tab-delimited data:

| Dataset | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| A | 2 | 20 |
| A | 3 | 30 |
| B | 1 | 40 |
| B | 2 | 50 |
| B | 3 | 60 |

I'd like to convert to the following:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 40 |
| 2 | 20 | 50 |
| 3 | 30 | 60 |

I know how to do this in r and python however this is a very large file with ~600 different Datasets and ~30,000 different IDs

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Why aren't R and Python suitable? Especially if you've already got a working solution? I would doubt that `awk` or `perl` would be any faster, for example

Comment: Hi roaima, thank you for the reply. I don't have the memory capacity. Its a ~60gb file and was hoping to operate on it directly

Comment: Could you add that to your question please. It's an important factor when considering alternative solutions

Comment: [edit] your question to replace the graphical representations of tables with actual textual sample input/output that we can copy/paste to test with so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
datamash crosstab 2,1 unique 3 < input.tsv > output.tsv
```

Comment: You said `I don't have the memory capacity. Its a ~60gb file and was hoping to operate on it directly` - I doubt if that solution is operating directly on the file instead of reading it into memory.